# Understanding a recursive function

Tags: c, algorithm

```
int Max_Subarray_Sum(int arr[], int n)  
{
    if(n == 1)
    {
        return arr[0];   // what it will be return for right Sub array
    }
    int m = n / 2;
    int left_MSS = Max_Subarray_Sum(arr, m);
    int right_MSS = Max_Subarray_Sum(arr + m, n - m);  // why arr+m will d0
    int leftsum = INT_MIN, rightsum = INT_MIN, sum = 0;
    for(int i = m; i < n; i++)
    {
        sum += arr[i];
        rightsum = max(rightsum, sum);
    }
    sum = 0;
    for(int i = (m-1); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        sum += arr[i];
        leftsum = max(leftsum,sum);
    }
}
```

I can't understand this piece of code, what will arr+m will do.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would it be more clear if the function declaration was written as: `int Max_Subarray_Sum(int *arr, int n)`?

Comment: It is not related to recursive function, look up for *pointer arithmetic* in C

Comment: For a small array, step through the code line by line in a debugger.

Comment: In C, the expression `*(arr + m)` is the same as `arr[m]`. That leads to `arr + m` being equal to `&arr[m]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can think of `arr` as a pointer to starting point of an array of integers. `arr + m` means the address of the `m`th element in the array, so this is basically splitting the array into two parts:

invoke recursive function on first `m` elements of the array:

```
int left_MSS = Max_Subarray_Sum(arr,m);
```

invoke recursive function on  last `n-m` elements of the array:

```
int right_MSS = Max_Subarray_Sum(arr+m,n-m);
```

Comment: if i am writing in java what should replace  `arr+m` to what

Comment: @user4018473 java is a different language, the operation `arr+m` is regarded as not safe and java does not allow it. In java you will either have to copy the two halves of the array using [`Arrays.copyOfRange()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(int[],%20int,%20int)), or add extra parameters that indicate the beginning of the array, and refer it as the new zero.

Comment: @user4018473 In java, you need to provide range in the parameters `Max_Subarray_Sum(array,start_index,end_index)` and use something like `for(int i=0; i<end_index-start_index; i++) sum += array[start_index+i];`

Answer (score 0):

```
int Max_Subarray_Sum(int arr[],int n)
{
    if(n==1)
    {
        return arr[0];   // what it will be return for right Sub array
    }
    int m = n/2;
    int left_MSS = Max_Subarray_Sum(arr,m);
    int right_MSS = Max_Subarray_Sum(arr+m,n-m);  // why arr+m will d0
    return left_MSS + right_MSS;
}
```

this should work. You forgot to add the last return. I also removed the for loop since its results will be thrown away.
this function splits the array into subarrays until it contains only 1 value.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected function:

```
int Max_Subarray_Sum(int arr[],int n)   
{
  if(n==1)
  {
    return arr[0];   // what it will be return for right Sub array
  }
  int m = n/2;
  int left_MSS = Max_Subarray_Sum(arr,m);
  int right_MSS = Max_Subarray_Sum(arr+m,n-m);  // why arr+m will d0
  return left_MSS + right_MSS;        
}
```

Explanation:
Say, 1st Call: Max_Subarray_Sum({4, 2, 5}, 3)

```
Max_Subarray_Sum({4, 2, 5}, 3)
= Max_Subarray_Sum({4}, 1) + Max_Subarray_Sum({2, 5}, 2)
= 4 + Max_Subarray_Sum({2}, 1) + Max_Subarray_Sum({5}, 1)
= 4 + 2 + 5
= 11
```